# AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, xssf

I get the error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject

I get that error when I am trying to open an excel file using java. See the code below. I have downloaded the lib Log4J and included the jar file in my class path. What should I do to make this work?

```
try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(C:/Users/myname/Desktop/result/Test1.xlsx));
        // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>RemoveBlankspaceFromExceldocuments</groupId>
    <artifactId>RemoveBlankspaceFromExceldocuments</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>



    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </build>

<dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are not using Maven to manage your library dependencies. You seem to have included the Apache POI library, but not its transitive dependencies, one of which is Apache XML Beans. I would highly recommend not continuing without Maven, Gradle, or another dependendy management system.

Comment: I converted the project to a Maven project and tried to add the dependency: <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>                                                                              To the pom file. It still didn't work.

Comment: 1. What do you think is the link between your error and Log4j? 2. If you now have Maven, why did you not include the Apache POI library in the dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Download xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar file [from http://book2s.com/java/jar/x/xmlbeans/download-xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar.html ]
2. Add the jar in Libraries.

It solved the *Exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject* issue.

Hope it will work for sure!